# Orchard MultiTenancy - Where are the tenants located?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm a developer that wishes to have a landlord site which manages tenants via Orchard. I've Enabled the Orchard.MultiTenancy module, started using it and created multiple sites for my purposes. 
However, I'm still somewhat in favor of coding stuff and not just edit it via a high-level Orchard user.

Trying to find each tenant's MVC site wasn't successful.
Any suggestions ?

If one tenant crashes, does it take with it all the other tenants (since I can't seem to find an Application Domain for each)?

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly get your question, multi-tenancy means there is only one code base. Each site is located in App_Data/Sites and has each sites settings.txt and database mappings but uses the core sites code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of multi-tenancy is to increase site density by letting multiple Orchard sites live in a single IIS application. There is not one site per tenant. The tenants are only separated in the DB, but all share the same files.

If a tenant crashes, well, it depends on the crash. Most exceptions won't even take out the tenant.